# How can I create amazing photographs with a Nikon Coolpix AW120?

Tags: nikon

My dad has a Nikon Coolpix AW120. He doesn't use it much, so I use it to do my photography stuff. I need some tips on how I can create amazing photographs using this point and shoot camera.

Comment: This is way, way too broad for us to be able to answer. There are an infinite variety of ways to create amazing photographs with any camera.

Answer (score 6):

This answer actually applies to any camera.  It's not immediate, but is guaranteed to be effective.

1. Pick up camera.
2. Create a series of photographs you think might work.
3. Later, review those photographs and decide which you think *did* work best.
4. The next day or week, go back to step 1. Repeat 1-3 until you feel comfortable.
5. Over time, look again at your favorite work. Print some of it out. Keep reflecting on what you've learned and what you think you could do better.
6. And keep going back to steps 1-5 until you have achieved mastery. (This will take many years.)

Comment: Also, learn the essentials:
aka the exposure, composition, lighting, and the technical terms like ISO and things like that.

Try to avoid auto.

Comment: You can learn those things if you want to. Many people find them helpful, but they're not really _the essence_. (See [David Fair explain how to play guitar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt1At1Fq8dE).) I do agree that getting the camera off of auto is likely to be an important move somewhere in the process. For getting some of these basics, take a look at this site's [most common questions](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) — and if there's something specific you don't understand after basic research, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This could be downvoted but I think it is the most exact answer.

> How I can create amazing photographs

- Learn, and practice.
- Learn, and practice.
- Learn, and practice.

Comment: It's basically what I said, isn't it?

Comment: Yeap, but your's is actually a methodology. Mine is not. :o)

Answer (score 0):

The AW-120 can be a great learning tool as you perfect your technique and skills.

You should be able to take okay photos with the AW120, but it will be difficult to to create "Amazing" photos. This camera has lots of compromises in order to fill the need of a compact waterproof camera.

One important aspect of a great camera is the ability to shoot RAW images. The tiny image sensor and lack of RAW capability means your photos can never look as good as a DSLR or even a more advanced Point and Shoot camera.

[AW-130 Review](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/2014-15-waterproof-camera-roundup/5)

> In terms of color and exposure, the Coolpix AW120 does a fine job. As
> with the other cameras in this group, detail smudging can be a
> problem, with the Nikon being the worst offender. When viewed at 100%,
> photos almost look like watercolor paintings (which again, most
> consumers will not be doing). This makes it challenging to judge the
> sharpness of the lens. It's fairly sharp over most of the frame (at
> both wide and telephoto), though you will notice some corner blurring.
>
> The AW120 produces acceptable results at ISO 400, as long as you're
> not viewing photos at 100% on your computer display.
>
> While the AW120's images look good when downsized - which is how most
> consumers will view them - upon closer inspection you'll see a lot of
> smudged details, giving pictures a watercolor look.
>
> heavy noise reduction smears away detail in photos.
>
> Cons:
> Mushy detail in photos
> Display hard to see outdoors
> Blue color cast underwater (often)

Answer (score 0):

Creating amazing photographs with your camera basically comes down to thinking up amazing photographs to take, and knowing how to use your camera to take them.  It's not so much about the camera as it is about you.

On the plus side, you have a waterproof and shockproof camera that you can take into situations most other cameras wouldn't be risked by their owners.

Because the AW120 is basically a point-and-shoot camera, without RAW, without a flash hotshoe, and without any way to explicitly set the exposure settings of shutter speed and aperture, **the main way you're going to have to learn photography with the AW120 is through mastering *composition***.

How you frame and aim is going to be your main weapon of choice.  I'd recommend doing some research on composition, and read a variety of books on the subject by a variety of authors (and not only in photography, but possibly also in cinematography, drawing, and painting), all the while filtering their advice through your own personal sense of taste and understand that, as with any art, there are no hard-and-fast rules; just guidelines.  Breaking rules can be as important to creating a piece as following them.

One book I'd recommend to get started on the basics of composition is Bryan Peterson's book, *[Learning to See Creatively](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817441816).*  Unlike a lot of other books on the subject (e.g., Michael Freeman's *The Photographer's Eye*, which is another great book), it doesn't present composition choices as bad/good so much as cause/effect.  And thus is more suitable for a beginner who hasn't quite figured out their place on the spectrum of compositional taste.